# Coupled pendulum, energy exchange period as a function of different lengths

Tags: coupled-oscillators, normal-modes

The energy exchange period $T_{x}$ of a coupled pendulum with coupling strength $\mu$ in the symmetric case(where the two natural frequencies with equal masses and equal lengths are the same, i.e. $\omega_{1}=\omega_{2}$) is given by 
\begin{equation}
T_{x}= 4\pi\omega_{1}/\mu^{2}.
\end{equation}

How can one find $T_{x}$ as a function of varying length of one of the two pendulums (keeping one length constant)?

Given the equations of motion for the displacements of the two pendulums
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_{1}= -\omega_{1}^{2}x_{1}+ \mu^{2}x_{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_{2}= -\omega_{2}^{2}x_{2}+ \mu^{2}x_{1}
\end{equation},
I have simplified this to get an expression for the normal mode frequencies $\omega_{\pm}$: 
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\pm}=1/2(\omega_{1}^{2}+\omega_{2}^{2})\pm 1/2 ((\omega_{1}^{2}-\omega_{2}^{2})^{2}+4\mu^{4})^{1/2}
\end{equation},

How can I solve for ${x}_{1}$ and ${x}_{2}$ in this case and then derive an expression for ${T}_{x}$?

Comment: III You can transform your equation to a diagonal shape by calculating the eigen values and eigenvectors $T^{T}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
-\omega ^{2}_{1} & \mu ^{2} \\
\mu ^{2} & -\omega ^{2}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot T=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda _{1} & 0 \\
0 & \lambda _{2}
\end{pmatrix}$ then you can easy write the solutions

Comment: I have derived both eigenvectors and eigenvalues, but I am not quite sure how to determine x1 and x2.

Comment: Please look hier https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284402/solving-system-of-linear-differential-equations-by-eigenvalues